# Is it safe to manually generate .appxsym and .appxupload for Windows Store Apps crash analysis?

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps, pdb-files, dotfuscator, appx

We have an app with a manual packaging process (MakeAppx.exe). We would like to publish this app to the Store including the public symbols files, so that I can download the .cab process dump file for crash analysis ([such as described here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh967782.aspx)).

I understand the .appxupload is a zip-file contaning the .appx package and an .appxsym file, which in turn is a .zip file containing the .pdb files ([also according to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975357.aspx)).

Is it safe to manually generate/edit these .appxsym and .appxupload for publishing?

Comment: I'm not a canonical source, but I have been doing this for about a year now and it has worked fine. I require this process in order for me to use programs like Dotfuscator for obfuscation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. This is fine. As you note, the appxupload's format is [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh975357.aspx) as being a zip archive containing the .appx and .appxsym files, and the .appxsym file is a compressed file with the app's public symbols. The appx and its creation is documented in [App packages and deployment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh464929.aspx#windows_runtime_app_packages___.appx)

Generating this yourself or generating it through VS will give essentially identical results, barring differences in the appxupload's contents (most likely different appx options or processing).